# Stop 100% rollout Google Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have started rolling out a new version of our APK to our users. Unfortunately during rollout I've mistakenly pushed 100% rollout to PROD. I do believe it's an ok build but I wanted to halt the rollout.

Is there a way to stop it? Currently it is still **in review** but I can't find a way which is weird.